# How to handle errors on save for a nested resource, when the new form is on parent's show template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've two resources `Team` and `Player`. Player is a nested resource under Team in my `routes.rb`.

For Team, I have a `show` action with `show.html.erb` template. In that template, I have something like `form_for [@team, @team.players.build]`, so basically I can create a new player from the team view.

Now what is the best way to code rendering/redirecting in the controller for `Player#create` on *error*? In a standard create action I would render the `new` action with errors:

```
  if @player.save
    redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
```

But now I'm now in a different controller (`Player#create`), while my form is in `Team#show`. If on error I redirect to @team, like on success, I will loose the error information stored in the instance variable. Is it better to try and render `team/show.html.erb`? This looks kind of messy. Or maybe add the create action for Player into the Team controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options for you:

1. Use `flash` to handle the error messages.  You won't have the instance variable available, but whatever you would have rendered can go in `flash[:error]` and used in Team#show.
2. Use a remote request with a json response.  You don't need to redirect at all, just return a json object containing a partial for the new player (on success), or an error message (on error).  Handle the response in the remote callback to update the page accordingly.
3. Move the player creation logic to the Team controller.  I would do this only if none of the other options were viable.

Comment: Option #1 is one that I would go with myself.

Comment: I thought about using redirect and flash, but I'd either have to only use a simple error message, or somehow shove all the @player.error.full_messages into flash. Since I'll do the remote request anyway (this question is actually only for the fallback functionality without JS), I think I'll go with the simple message in flash.

Comment: I went with 1 for standard form submit (fallback) and 2 for ajax.